# Compile a java file using javac

Tags: java, cmd, windows-8.1, javac

Ok now it feels like I've tried everything, can someone please tell me how I can compile a Java file ? My file/code looks like this:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

And I have saved it as `HelloWorld.java` and in All Files. But the problem is that everytime I try to compile the Java file it says:

> 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I have downloaded `JDK` and `JRE`, set/changed the path to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin;` but when I look through the commands I can't see the `javac` command anywhere!

I thought for a while that I may have downloaded the wrong `JDK`, but when I see what's supposed to include in `JDK` it says that javac is supposed to be there too - but I can't find it!

Any suggestion how to fix this ?

I use `Windows 8.1` (I don't know if that helps but I write it just in case). I really need some help I've been trying to fix this for about 6 months now and it's getting really annoying not know what to do.

Comment: @GregHilston I would say it's different. Op just pointed to the wrong installation (jre not jdk) that question is more about how to set the path

Comment: @GregHilston I've already looked at it a few times and I've tried it and it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having the path `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin` won't help you with the Java compiler `javac`, which is in the Java Development Kit (JDK) rather than the Java Runtime Environment (JRE).

As a first step, make sure your path includes a `bin` directory from some directory with "jdk" in the name.

I see that you've downloaded `jdk-8u51-windows-x64.exe`, which is (what I presume to be) the JDK installer. If it is the JDK installer from a reputable source, run it and and it should produce an directory containing the JDK in a predictable place (such as adjacent to the JRE, or in the root `C:` directory as *seanhodges* helpfully commented below).

Comment: The JDK path would have been the "Install to" path specified on this page in the installer: http://codingfox.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/JDK-5.png

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your java's installation bin folder to your windows path.

Additionally, the path you set was the the JRE not the JDK. You need the JDK to compile code.

https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Answer (score 1):

`javac` can be found in the JDK directory - `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin` is a JRE directory. JDK directories start with `jdk`.

Comment: I've downloaded jdk-8u51-windows-x64.exe

Comment: Just to be sure: you also installed it? Downloading is not enough. Also, you can just search for `javac.exe` in the Windows Explorer.

Comment: Yes of course I've installed it

Answer (score 1):

Before all, make sure you understand the differences between a *JRE* and a *JDK*:

- The *JRE* (Java Runtime Environment) is used to execute java programs
- The *JDK* (Java Development Kit) is used to compile java source code (and embed a *JRE*)

If you look into the `bin` folder inside your *JDK* installation path, you may find, among other commands, `javac`.

So all you have to do is to [configure some environment variables](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-edit-environment-variables-quickly-in-windows-8-1-and-windows-8/):

- `JAVA_HOME` to your JDK installation path, most likely `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51`.
- `PATH`, you should append `:$JAVA_HOME$\bin` to the existing path.

Then, you may be able to execute `javac HelloWorld.java` in a terminal without problem, since `javac` is available in the `%PATH%`